# initialization of non-const reference of type 'char*&' from a temporary of type 'char*'

Tags: c++, reference

```
void test3(char * &p){
    strcpy( p, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
}


char c[] = "123";
test3(c);
```

---

the code above is compiled failed:

> initialization of non-const reference of type 'char*&' from a temporary of type 'char*'

why `char c[]` can't be referenced by the argument `p`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the type of `c` is `char[4]`, i.e. an *aray of four `char`s.* Your reference needs a `char*`, i.e. a *pointer to `char`.*

Arrays are not pointers. In most cases, they *decay to a pointer to first element* when used, but that decay-produced pointer is *temporary.* As such, it cannot bind to a non-const reference.

Why is your function taking a reference in the first place? It would be perfectly fine taking `char*`.

Comment: Can you please provide some input on my answer. I'm a newbie. thanks! And I know that it might not be a safe thing to do to change the type before passing it to the function

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your code by taking an intermediate variable as:

```
char c[] = "123";
char* tmp = c;
test3(tmp);
```

And as you are trying to copy a relatively longer string than the length, you may corrupt the variable.

Comment: In the OP's case, this will work (and, as you correctly say, corrupt memory beyond `c[3]`). In the general case, if `test3()` was modifying `p`, it would modify `tmp`. If the author expected it to modify `c` somehow (i.e. make it point to a different address), they could be surprised. Of course, making `c` point to a different address is impossible - `c` is not a pointer. So yours is the correct way to use the `test3()` function as it stands; but that `test3()`'s interface does not match its semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your code by adding a modifier, "const",
promisng that you won't change the address of c :

```
void test3(char * const &p){
    strcpy( p, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
}


char c[] = "123";
test3(c);
```